# Firebase hosting: Serve different pages from different custom domains

Tags: firebase, subdomain, firebase-hosting

We're using custom domains on firebase hosting: our app, served from index.html, runs nicely on app.example.com. We've also connected www.example.com, which serves the app as well.

The problem is: on www.example.com I want to be able to host a simple static page. Is there a way to configure this in the rewrites? We can easily output an extra html file in the deploy, next to index.html.

Any ideas?

Our firebase.json:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: it's possible to have multiple sites now. please refere https://stackoverflow.com/a/52090622/1608832

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Firebase Hosting does not support multiple sites in a single project at this time. However, you can create a second project for your static landing page and deploy it there, connecting it to the `www` domain while leaving the app domain connected to the other project.</strike>

As of August of 2018, Firebase Hosting supports multiple sites on a single project! See [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. We know about this possibility, but we were hoping we could do rewrites on domain level. Maybe in the future!

Comment: Is this still true? Today, I see "Firebase Hosting supports multiple sites" in the Firebase Console - Hosting.

Comment: Good catch! I hadn't updated it since the feature launched in August.