# Correct way of subdomain configuration

Tags: angularjs, firebase, subdomain, firebase-hosting

I am setting up my first website and currently am confused when it comes to properly configuring the subdomains.

I have got a domain from **GoDaddy** which is, let's say *website.com*. Then, I am using **Firebase** for my hosting, database and so on. I managed to register my domain for the Firebase hosting service and that works just fine and I am able to access it properly.

Then I wanted to **add two new subdomains** which are *sub1.website.com* and *sub2.website.com*. First, I went to Firebase console and added those two new subdomains. Then I registered those A (or whatever was the name) entries on my GoDaddy console as requested by Firebase.

After that, I **created two subfolders** - *sub1* and *sub2* - in my public directory for my project, added different *index.html* files in each and deployed hosting to Firebase. Then I **was able to access** my subdomains at *website.com/sub1* and *website.com/sub2*, but when I went to either *sub1.website.com* or *sub2.website.com*, it **redirected** me to the main page - *website.com*.

I want to know what I am doing wrong. I searched for answers here on SO and Google, but was not able to find the proper fix just yet. Please help me to resolve this silly issue.

P.S. I am using AngularJS for web development, if that changes anything.

Comment: Firebase Hosting does not map subfolders to subdomains. All domains tied to a single project will serve the same content. To serve different content for each subdomain, you'll need to create a separate project for each subdomain. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44047865/firebase-hosting-serve-different-pages-from-different-custom-domains

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I was not able to find the previous  answer (that you posted), but now I know. :)